# validate username ajax and json and asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

> Hello,
>
> ```
> I am trying to verify if a username is taken or available by
> ```
>
> using jquery to send a request to an
>   asp.net page.  The ASP.net page is
>   clearly getting the information as I
>   am having it make an entry into a log
>   database. My SQL server database
>   indeed shows the username being passed
>   to it and is returning a value however
>   for some reason the client side
>   html/javascript doesn't RESPOND to it.
>   I am not sure if it is on the end of
>   my html/javascript or perhaps my
>   asp.net page is not returning the json
>   information correctly?  This is my
>   first attempt at json
>
> The checking availability box shows up
>   on the html page but it NEVER changes
>   even when the sql server shows that it
>   ran the stored procedure

Html File

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var validateUsername = $('#validateUsername');
        $('#username').keyup(function () {
            var t = this;
            if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
                if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
                validateUsername.removeClass('error').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" height="16" width="16" /> checking availability...');

                this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ValidateUsername.aspx',
                        data: 'username=' + t.value,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'get',
                        success: function (j) {
                            validateUsername.html('HI!');
                        }
                    });
                }, 200);

                this.lastValue = this.value;
            }
        });
    });
```

//-->

Username, valid: a-z.-_

```
asp.net page [CheckusernameAvailable.aspx]

<%@  Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CheckUsernameAvailable.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Services_UsernameAvailable" %>
```

Asp.net code behind asp.net page [CheckusernameAvailable.aspx.cs]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using UserSite.DataClasses;
using System.Data;

namespace OohruWeb
{
    public partial class ValidateUsername : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string NameToLookUp = Request.QueryString["username"];
            if (NameToLookUp == null) {
                NameToLookUp = "";
            }
            DbaseExecSpWithReturnValue Sproc = new DbaseExecSpWithReturnValue();
            Sproc.SetSp("sp_CheckUsernameAvailable");
            Sproc.AddParam(1);
            Sproc.AddParam("Username",SqlDbType.Char,NameToLookUp,20);
            int RetVal = Sproc.Execute();
            Sproc.Close();
            if (RetVal == 0)
            {
                Response.Write(@"'{""success"": false}'");
            }
            if (RetVal == 1)
            {
                Response.Write(@"'{""success"": true}'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see a response when using firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you need to decorate your method with the `[WebMethod]` attribute *and* the class needs to be decorated so that it is exposed to client side script. I usually use a web service file, `.asmx`.

In fact I'm not sure if you can use a regular class file like you have, but create a web service file and reference the code it uses, and apply it to your own file to see if it works.

Also, I'm surprised your code is working, your data parameter doesn't look like it's in `json` format. Should be `data: "{ }"` as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Response.Clear()` and `Response.End()` to see if that takes care of your problem.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string NameToLookUp = Request.QueryString["username"];
        if (NameToLookUp == null) {
            NameToLookUp = "";
        }
        DbaseExecSpWithReturnValue Sproc = new DbaseExecSpWithReturnValue();
        Sproc.SetSp("sp_CheckUsernameAvailable");
        Sproc.AddParam(1);
        Sproc.AddParam("Username",SqlDbType.Char,NameToLookUp,20);
        int RetVal = Sproc.Execute();
        Sproc.Close();
        if (RetVal == 0)
        {
            Response.Write(@"'{""success"": false}'");
        }
        if (RetVal == 1)
        {
            Response.Write(@"'{""success"": true}'");
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```